# POWERBI: 4 Arguments were passed to a function which expects between 2 and 3

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to add `[CommandTimeOut=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0),ConnectionTimeout=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0)]` to get rid of all timeout errors.

`= Sql.Database("server1\DB","TBL",[Query="long query"],[CommandTimeOut=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0),ConnectionTimeout=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0)])`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument is a single record. Try:

```
= Sql.Database("server1\DB","TBL",[Query="long query", CommandTimeOut=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0),ConnectionTimeout=#duration(0, 2, 0, 0)])
```

Comment: Hi, now I am getting this instead - DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: This function doesn't support the query option 'CommandTimeOut' with value '#duration(0, 2, 0, 0)'.
Details:

Comment: You have the case wrong. Try: CommandTimeout

Comment: Oh wow, case sensitive. Didn't know about this. Thank you very much David!